# Proving Ramsey numbers.

Tags: combinatorial-geometry

Please how do I prove the following Ramsey numbers:

$R(4,5)=34$  and     $R(5)=68$

I know i am supposed to start with the pigeonhole principle to determine colored edges and check for different cases. I also know that the vertices generated also play a role in the proof. However, I do not know how to start and proceed. Please I need your help with the proof.

Comment: Your numbers do not seem to agree with the table given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Ramsey_numbers). Are you perhaps defining them in a different way?

Comment: Computing specific Ramsey numbers is hard.  One can find upper limits relatively easily, but they are enormous compared to the real answers.  The real answers, as far as I know, just come from a tree search of the possibilities.  You need clever pruning of the tree to make it accessible on the computer(s) you have available.

Comment: I think it is slightly defined differently. An example to prove R(3,4)=10 is as follows: There are nine edges on vertex v.

Comment: I think it is slightly defined differently. An example to prove R(3,4)=10 is as follows: (First color is green, second color is red). Let v be a vertex.There are nine edges on vertex v. Then either four green edges on v or six red edges The first case is four green edges on v which means either one of the edges is green (then we are done)or all of them are red(we are also done). The second case is to consider the other 6 endpoints; R(3)=6, R(3,3)=6. So there is either a green triangle on those six points or a red triangle. We are done in either of those.That was the example for R(3,4)=10.

Comment: Maybe if it's defined slightly differently, and your definition is *not* the standard one that gives $R(3,4) = 9$, you could say exactly what definition you are using?

Comment: The error was just corrected in class. Actually, R(3,4)=9. Also,THE QUESTION IS AS FOLLOWS: PROVE R(4,5)=25, R(3,5)=14, R(4,4)=18. Thanks for noticing that and I will appreciate the help.